# Update document reference with Location.reload()

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, vbscript

So I'm writing a script in Visual basics to fill out an online form. I'm able to fill out the first form, but after submitting the first the page refreshes with a new form but the internet explorer object is stuck on the previous html. I think if i call Location.reload() then it will refresh the html document, but I'm unable to figure out how to call it.

```
Dim coName As String
Dim usrName As String
Dim pwd As String


Dim wb As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Set wb = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
wb.Visible = True
wb.Navigate("*************")
While wb.Busy
    Wait 0.100
Wend

wb.Document.getElementById("txt_CID").Value = "*****"
wb.Document.getElementById("txt_UID").Value = "**********"
wb.Document.getElementById("txt_PWD").Value = "*****"
wb.Document.getElementById("btnLogin").Click()
wb.Visible = True

Wait 2 (..............New Page loads here..............)

wb.Document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTechID").Value = "IP3M-01"
```

The last line gives the error: "not an object reference" because the document hasn't updated.

Sadly, I must use vbscript so I need to figure out how to make this work.

update:
I was able call location.reload() through the document object, although microsoft's documentation didn't show that you could do that...

now the error has gone away but I think the internet explorer browser object is still stuck on the previous document... the only way I know how to fix this is to call wb.Navigate("url") but this also clears the form which Im trying to automate.

Comment: Please confirm this is vbscript and not VBA, since you don't define variable types like VBA does. Plus, `New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` won't work in VBS.